# Unit test for only root user in python

Tags: python

Does unit test library for python (especially 3.x, I don't really care about 2.x) has decorator to be accessed only by root user?

I have this testing function.

```
def test_blabla_as_root():
    self.assertEqual(blabla(), 1)
```

blabla function can only be executed by root. I want root user only decorator so normal user will skip this test:

```
@support.root_only
def test_blabla_as_root():
    self.assertEqual(blabla(), 1)
```

Does such decorator exist? We have @support.cpython_only decorator though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using unittest, you can skip tests or entire test cases using `unittest.skipIf` and `unittest.skipUnless`.

Here, you could do:

```
import os

@unittest.skipUnless(os.getuid() == 0)  # Root has an uid of 0
def test_bla_as_root(self):
    ...
```

Which could be simplified in a (less readable):

```
@unittest.skipIf(os.getuid())
```